# Chrome sniffing http2 packets

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, hook, http2

I have some problems with sniffing chrome http2. I use NetRipper with modified signatures in order to hook functions and I can't find out http2 packets in SSL_Read hook. Do somebody have a solution for that or some extra information in order to figure it out?
NetRipper captures broken packets.

Comment: Don’t understand your question or your problem but Wireshark allows you to sniff all http2 traffic from Chrome if you export the SSL key.

Comment: no, that's not what I really want. I'm interested in getting it through hooks and I face some problems hooking boringssl read and write functions. I can't find needed data there